# Casting id to pointer to an NSError pointer (NSError **)

Tags: objective-c, pointers, nserror

I have an `NSError **` stored in an array (so I can get it as such `array[0]`). I'm trying to cast it into a variable:

`NSError * __autoreleasing *errorPointer = (NSError * __autoreleasing *)array[0];`

so I can access the underlying object as `*errorPointer`.

However, Xcode complains that `Cast of an Objective-C pointer to 'NSError *__autoreleasing *' is disallowed with ARC`. Is there any way to get to this object without turning off ARC?

Comment: Why are you storing as `NSError **` rather than just `NSError *`?

Comment: I want whoever passed in the pointer, to have the error object available as well. This is a common pattern in Cocoa, the pointers are usually passed in directly as arguments, not stored in an array, though.

Comment: It's common when passed to a method, yes, but I don't see how it works when you are storing the `NSError` object in an array.

Comment: You need an address-of to take double pointers, and really, don't screw with NSArray's pointer storing mechanism like this.  Autoreleasing parameters are meant for locals.

Comment: I'm not using it in production code. In Kiwi, the unit test framework I use, there is a method which allows you to stub a selector and replace its code with any block. It passes all the method parameters in an array: `[beer stub:@selector(drinkByHand:error:) withBlock: id ^(NSArray *params) { Hand *hand = (Hand *)params[0]; // here I want to get the error and fill it in, so I can simulate a failure; return nil; }];`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither that `stub:withBlock:` method or any of its supporting infrastructure could be simply stuffing a double pointer into an `NSArray`. The array won't take non-objects, and a pointer to an object is not an object. There's something else going on.

This obviously requires some digging into the code to figure out. Where does the value get put into the array? That's in [`-[KWStub processInvocation:]`](https://github.com/allending/Kiwi/blob/master/Classes/KWStub.m#L177), and it's done apparently using a method added to `NSInvocation` by OCMock, [`getArgumentAtIndexAsObject:`](http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/third_party/ocmock/OCMock/NSInvocation+OCMAdditions.m). In that method, the invocation uses a switch to check the type of the argument that is requested, and boxes it up if necessary.

The relevant case here is the last one, where the argument type is `^`, meaning "pointer". This sort of argument is wrapped up in an `NSValue`; therefore, the array recieved by your Block actually contains, not the double pointer itself, but an `NSValue` representing the outer pointer. You just need to unbox it.

That should look like this:

```
NSValue * errVal = array[1];
NSError * __autoreleasing * errPtr = (NSError * __autoreleasing *)[errVal pointerValue];
```

Comment: The link broke! Where the heck did `KWStub` go?

Comment: I've moved files around when converting Kiwi to ARC, that method is here now: https://github.com/allending/Kiwi/blob/master/NonARC/KWStub.m#L180

Comment: Thanks! Is there a corresponding method for the ARC version that I should link to?

Comment: @JoshCaswell thank's your solution works. I also tried to do the same with `memcpy` It's a little shorter, but i am not sure if it is correct: `memcpy([array[1] pointerValue], (void *)&error, sizeof(NSError **));` (instead the two of your lines + `*errPtr = error;`)  Could you have a look please?